# Зачем нужно return this, внутри класса Builder, в шаблоне Builder

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, процедуры, this, return

```
public class BuilderLesson {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car lada = new Car.Builder("Лада").setColour("Белый").setMinSpeed(0).build();

        lada.getColour();
        lada.getMinSpeed();

    }

}

class Car {

    private String name;
    private String colour = "Black";
    private int maxSpeed = 250;
    private int minSpeed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getColour() {
        return colour;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public int getMinSpeed() {
        return minSpeed;
    }

    private Car(Builder builder) {

        this.name = builder.name;
        this.colour = builder.colour;
        this.maxSpeed = builder.maxSpeed;
        this.minSpeed = builder.minSpeed;

    }

    static class Builder {

        private String name;
        private String colour = "Black";
        private int maxSpeed = 250;
        private int minSpeed;

        public Builder(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public Builder setColour(String colour) {
            this.colour = colour;
            return this; // Для чего тут
        }

        public Builder setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
            this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
            return this; // Тут
        }

        public Builder setMinSpeed(int minSpeed) {
            this.minSpeed = minSpeed;
            return this; // И тут, возвращать this
        }

        public Car build() {
            return new Car(this);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: чтобы вызовы в цепочке объединять.

Comment: Что бы можно было сделать так `builder.setColor(...).setMaxSpeed(...).setMinSpeed(...);`

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Это то понятно)) Мне нужно поглубже понять, я не хочу просто запоминать

Comment: В данном примере наблюдается использование шаблона https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: @АльбертПетров что понять? ФП? Почитайте книги по "ФП" в яве. Вон вам человек выше скинул щаблон по которому это сделано.

Comment: Fluent интерфейсы используются в Stream API. Когда вы пишите(если вы пишите конечно) `stream.of(...).map(...).filter(...)...`  - то там каждый метод(кроме терминальных) возвращает объект `Stream`, благодаря чему  и получается такая цепочка методов

Comment: @Anton Sorokin Ладно, пока запомню как правило, спасибо. Функциональное программирование в Java нужно понять лучше, ясно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас применен шаблон [Builder](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/builder.php) и шаблон [Fluent Interface](https://java-design-patterns.com/patterns/fluentinterface/).

Fluent Interface - это интерфейс который предоставляет цепочки методов(как стримы). Он состоит из двух типов методов: **cascade method** и **chaining method**.

**Cascade method**: что-то делает с `this`, возвращает `this`;

**Chaining method**: что-то делает с новым объектом созданным с помощью `this`, возвращает новый объект.

Сделано это для улучшения читаемости и упрощения кода.

Пример без шаблона:

```
A a = new A(...);
a.setName(...);
a.setAge(...);
a.setColor(...);
    ...
```

Пример с шаблоном Fluent Interface(без Builder):

```
A a = new A(...);
a.setName(...).setAge(...).setColor(...)...
```

Сделать такую цепочку методов можно из-за того что каждый метод используется с объектом `A`, и каждый метод возвращает объект `A`.

Т.е., примерно так: `a.setName(...){тут возвращаем a}.setAge(...){тут возвращаем a}.setColor(...){тут возвращаем a}...`

Пример с библиотекой Stream API:

```
list = list.stream()
         .map(x -> x/2)
         .filter(x -> x % 3 == 3)
         .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` возвращается для реализации цепочки вызова методов (method chaining), чтобы следующий метод в цепочке вызовов мог обратиться к тому же объекту (`this`  - это ссылка на текущий объект) и не требовалось каждый раз обращаться к первоначально созданному:

```
obj.method1().method2();
```

вместо

```
obj.method1(); 
obj.method2();
```

при обработке строки из первого примера в классе `obj` будет вызван `method1()`, который результатом своей работы через `this` вернет этот же объект `obj`, то есть, после выполнения метода  часть `obj.method1()` будет как бы заменена на `obj` и для него уже будет вызван `method2()` и так далее для всей цепочки объект будет передаваться от метода к методу через `this`, который эти методы возвращают.